# transform.forward only works on 0,0,0 rotaion, I want to make it indepent of rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `Camera` script, which follow tank, and makes an empty `GameObject` name as target, and I assign new position forward from camera to target, and tank only look to this target `GameObject`, working fine if `Camera` is at 0,0,0, rotation, but if I changed its rotation from inspector let say 0,145,0.. then its not working fine, target `GameObject` goes don't know which position, here is my code so far

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform tank;
private Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 250.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -20.0f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80.0f;

private float x;
private float y;

public float heightOffset = 0;

void Awake()
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.x;
    y = angles.y;
    GameObject newTarget = new GameObject("target");
    target = newTarget.transform;
    FindObjectOfType<TankGunController>().target = target;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (tank != null)
    {
        x += (float)(Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * xSpeed * 0.02f);
        y -= (float)(Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f);
        y = ClampAngle (y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        Vector3 position = rotation * (new Vector3 (0.0f, heightOffset, -distance)) + tank.position;

        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
        target.position = transform.position + (transform.forward * 100);
     }
}

private float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360)
    {
        angle += 360;
    }
    if (angle > 360)
    {
        angle -= 360;
    }
    return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[transform.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) is always "in the forward direction of the transform" - yes, it takes rotation into account which is really useful in most cases.

If you don't want that, use [Vector3.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-forward.html) instead - that's a globally constant direction.

Also, use "Time.deltaTime" as a factor in Update and LateUpdate (but not FixedUpdate) - frames take different amount of ms to finish, depending on game state but also depending on pc.

using:

```
transform.position += Vector3.forward * 1000 * Time.deltaTime;
```

will be frame-rate independent and run smoother overall, compared to:

```
transform.position += Vector3.forward * 100;
```

edit: what I wrote is useful if you increase something over time. I just realized you are not adding like `position = position + X` (similar to `position += X`) but actually assigning an offset to target. Sorry about that, in this case ignore the deltaTime.

use

```
target.position = transform.position + (Vector3.forward * 100);
```

if it's "to the left" instead of "forward" then use another axis, like Vector3.right - these are global directions but it depends on your camera view of course.